# How do I extract the value 72 from this string

Tags: dictionary, nested

How do I extract the value 72 from this string?

```
{'rssi' : '+' , 'source_addr' : '\x00\x02' , 'samples' : [{'adc-0' : 72}] , 'options' : '\x00'}
```

`.get('samples')` gives me `[{'adc-0' : 72}]` but I do not know how to extract the value 72 from this?

What does the `[{a:b}]` type structure signify?

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what language you are using and what is it all about, but if an input is JSON then `[{a:b}]` is a list of objects.

`.get('samples')` gives you a list `[{'adc-0' : 72}]` which has one element: `{'adc-0' : 72}`, you need to take this first element of the list (or iterate the list), and I suppose you will call `.get('adc-0')` on the list element to get a value of 72.